# Why should I only allow image upload during DEBUG mode?

Tags: python, django, web-deployment, imagefield

I want to add a field for users to edit their profile pictures and checked out a few tutorials. However, every tutorial I've found included some form of this in urls.py:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT
```

Why can't I do this with deployment and if it has to be like this? Is there any way for me to allow users to upload and modify their profile pictures?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This is not about *uploading* images. This is about *serving* images: Django does not serve static/media files in production because that would be inefficient, and likely insecure.

Comment: But even without the `if settings.DEBUG` check, it will not serve the files.

Answer (score 0):

This is because in production mode django stop serving static files.
Thus static url will result in a page not found.